# How to find the sparsity of fully connected layer representing convolutional layer?

Tags: convolution, machine-learning, neural-networks

We can represent the convolutional layer exactly as a fully connected layer. Suppose we have a 2-D convolutional layer, with input size = 3x32x32, number of filters = 16, filter size = 3x3, stride = 1, padding = 0. Suppose all filter entries are non-zero. What's the sparsity (proportion of zero entries to the total number of entries) of the converted fully connected layer weight matrix?

Comment: A convolutional layer isn't fully connected. Fully connected means $y_l = f(W_l y_{l-1})$ where $W_l$ is a full matrix, for a convolutional layer $W_l$ is constrained to be a circulant matrix which is determined by much less parameters.

Comment: @reuns the question is asking if we choose to use fully connected layer instead of convolutional layer since they can be equivalent.

Comment: We can't represent a convolutional layer as a fully connected layer. In general you can say a layer is $y_l = f_l(W_l y_{l-1})$, $ f_l$ is a differentiable function acting diagonally and $W_l = \sum_{i=1}^{e_l} p_{l,i} M_{l,i}$ where the $M_{l,i}$ are fixed matrices and the $p_{l,i}$ are the real parameters to be optimized.